# How to transfer the data from input range to output range based on the condition in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to transfer my data (Price, Group, Location) from Input range to output range based on the number selected in cell `D5`.

For example, when I select Scenario 1 (drop down list) in the Input range and key in all the respective data, the data will be reflected in Output 1. When I select Scenario 2 in Input range, cell `D7:D9` will become empty again (the data in Output 1 will not gone) and ready for me to key in the data for Scenario 2. So, after I had typed in all the data, the data will be reflected in Output 2 as well. I'm trying to use `INDIRECT` function but I'm not sure how to do this I the same page. Please give me some ideas and really appreciated for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in G7:

```
=IF(D5=1; {D7:D9}; )
```

paste in G14:

```
=IF(D5=2; {D7:D9}; )
```

---

`INDIRECT` needs to be used only if Output 1 & 2 are on a different sheet

---

if you want to populate both Outputs from your input at the same time frame you will need a script